# PHP and ajax (GetSimple)

Tags: php, ajax

i have site on cms GetSimple and want to show 10 subpage and load another with ajax.

```
function getSubMenu($page){
```

```
$children=getChildren($page); 

foreach ($children as $subpage){ 
    $title=returnPageField($subpage,'title'); 
    $url=returnPageField($subpage,'slug'); 
    echo '<a href="/'.$url.'.html"> '.$title.'</a>'; 
}
```

} This code echo all subpage. How show only 10 subpage and another load after with ajax. Ajax i can do but correct php it is difficult for me. Thank if anyone will answer.

**Update**

```
function getSubMenu($page){
```

```
$children=getChildren($page); 
$i=0;
foreach ($children as $subpage){
    if($i==10) break; 
    $title=returnPageField($subpage,'title'); 
    $url=returnPageField($subpage,'slug'); 
    echo '<a href="/'.$url.'.html"> '.$title.'</a>';
    $i++;  
}
```

} This code show only 10. How make php function which show more subpage (number from ajax). For example ajax

```
$.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "",
                    context: this,
                    data: {
                              'num'       : '10'
                           },
                    success: function(data){
                      console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                      console.log('error' + data);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break out of the foreach loop by using this.

```
foreach ($children as $subpage){ 
    $title=returnPageField($subpage,'title'); 
    $url=returnPageField($subpage,'slug'); 
    echo '<a href="/'.$url.'.html"> '.$title.'</a>';
    $count++;
    if($count==10) break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I find this code, but i don't know how load more with ajax.